# Infinite Refresh Loop in Firefox 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a strange issue with my Javascript in Firefox 3.0.x. In Firefox 3.0.12, the page constantly reloads as soon as the list body is loaded. Neither Firefox 3.5, Safari 4 nor Chrome 5 (all on Mac) experience this issue.

**EDIT**: I've created an isolated example rather than pulling this from my existing code.

**The issue was related to a bug that caused the page to reload when setting location.hash to an empty string in FF 3.0.**

**test.js**

```
function welcomeIndexOnLoad() {
  $("#options a").live('click', function () {
    optionClicked($(this), "get_list_body.html");
    return false;
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    optionClicked(null, "get_list_body.html");
  });
}

function optionClicked(sender, URL) {
  queryString = "";
  if (sender != null) {
    queryString = $(sender).attr("rel");
  }
  $("#list_body").load(URL + "?" + queryString, function(resp, status, AJAXReq) {
    console.log(resp);
    console.log("" + status);
    location.hash = queryString;
  });
}​
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  <script>
    welcomeIndexOnLoad();
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
  Outside of list body.
  <div id="list_body">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**get_list_body.html**

```
<h3>
  <div id="options">
    <a href="#" rel="change_list">Change List</a>
  </div>
<ul>
  <li>li</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery line 5252 (an xhr.send() call) shows up in the console as soon as the page reloads:

```
xhr.send( type === "POST" || type === "PUT" || type === "DELETE" ? s.data : null );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much more searching, I came across this [blog post](http://www.creave.dk/post/2009/10/02/locationhash-javascript-bug-in-Firefox-30.aspx), which mentions that setting the location hash to an empty string in Firefox 3.0 causes the page to refresh.

Changing my default queryString to "#" rather than an empty string fixes the problem.

Comment: This does not seem to solve the issue I'm having on fennec browser on OnePlus 1.. 
I tried by replacing .load() with $.get() and $(selector).html. Still I'm getting the same issue. Any thoughts ?

Comment: I posted this over 5 years ago. I'm sure a ton has changed in Firefox so it's possible your issue is caused by something else. You should post a new question that someone with more experience with your particular setup may be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is the live function as it has a constant flow which never ends until a die() function is called. try and test it with `die().live(...)`

although sometimes it looks like it refreshes that may not be the case it may just be that the browser has badly handled the memory and that loop may exhaust it called memory leaking.

another reason could be your ajax page which loads many times over.